How to customize a client search and delete Endpoint to the Springboot Oauth2 Authorization server
I want to manage the oauth2 clients that was registered in the oauth2 authorization server, the clients are stored in the oauth2-registered-client table.
I see that oauth2 can enable the clientRegistrationEndpoint, it works fine, so I wonder if the client search and delete Endpoint have existed too, but I can't find it.
So, I created a user defined endpoint, then I sent a request with the Bearer token head, the response was a form login page (the scopes: message.read,message.write)

Currently, the RegisteredClientRepository does not have an update or delete operation out of the box. What you can do is, extend RegisteredClientRepository and implement your own logic to do the delete and update operations. After that, you can add a custom endpoint and point it to use the custom methods you implemented.
For searching, AFAIR, the get endpoint should be available. Something similar to GET <BASE_PATH>/connect/register?client_id=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>
For the second issue, you may need to disable security from your WebSecurityCustomizer and implement it in your controller.
